# Is there a way to save the function call with parameters?

Tags: c

I'm experimenting with memory management and trying to create something that will help with it in any way. Right now I'm trying to think is there any way to repeat the 'defer' functionality from Go in C.

Fast example for those who don't know what defer is:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer fmt.Println("1")
    defer fmt.Println("2")
    defer fmt.Println("3")
    return
}
```

will print

```
3
2
1
```

So I'm thinking about some macros that will push the function with params to some stack and will call them when the function exit is called. Something like this:

```
int func(void)
{
    MEMSTACK_INIT;

    char * string = NULL;
    node_t * node = NULL;
    MEMSTACK_PUSH(free(string));
    MEMSTACK_PUSH(NodeFree(&node));

    <..>

    switch (something)
    {
    case ONE : RETURN ERROR_ONE;
    case TWO : RETURN ERROR_TWO;
    case THR :
        switch (something else)
        {
            <.. Many more code ..>
        }
    }        

    RETURN ERROR_GOOD;
}
```

Is there a way (except for making my own preprocessor, of course), to store somewhere a function call with params? In other words I want the previous code to be preprocessed in something like this:

```
int func(void)
{
    <.. Some MEMSTACK initialisation stuff (if needed) ..>

    char * string = NULL;
    node_t * node = NULL;

    <..>

    switch (something)
    {
    case ONE :             
        free(string);
        NodeFree(&node);
        return ERROR_ONE;
    case TWO :             
        free(string);
        NodeFree(&node);
        return ERROR_TWO;
    case THR :
        switch (something else)
        {
            <.. Many more code ..>
        }
    }        

    free(string);
    NodeFree(&node);
    return ERROR_GOOD;
}
```

It would be good thing for functions who require a lot of cleanup before exit.
Yes, yes, I know about `goto cleanup` trick.

Comment: It looks like an interesting question, but unfortunately hard to understand... a lot of context is in your head but it should be here.

Comment: I don't know go, but deferred execution is not just reversing execution using a stack, but much more. Don't try to use such techniques in C. This will just obfuscate your code without support of the language and massively complicate debugging and maintenance. Note also that the stacking costs possibly more than direct execution (which is the major idea behind deferred execution).

Comment: You can copy the functor concept: bind data and method into a struct

Comment: @EugeneSh.: This is a too broad discussion question. Not suitable for stack overflow.

Comment: One of the major problems with implementing an approach like this is having a persistent and correctly-typed representation of a function's argument list.  At best, you could do this se[arately for each set of calls to functions with the same return type and the same sequence of argument types.

Comment: @user3528438, could you, please, explain, how to bind data? There's no big deal with memorising the method as far as I understand.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, what if to represent any `pushed` function as having `void *` arguments? That will remove 1/2 of the problem, as we can automatically expand every param as `paramname -> (void *)paramname`

Comment: @EugeneSh., I'm doing my best with explaining `defer` functionality. You can follow [this](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12) page to "touch" go's version. Hope this will help you with understanding my idea.

Comment: @AlexTiger, where the function's actual argument types are not pointers, representing them as `void *` or any other type of pointer is not guaranteed safe or reliable, nor is it standard-conforming without casts (which you cannot perform without specific knowledge of the argument types).  Where any of them is neither a pointer nor an integer, it is not conforming even with casts.

Comment: _Where any of them is neither a pointer nor an integer, it is not possible at all._ Then we can **make** it a pointer or integer (which is the same): `func(double aaa) -> func(somevar) -> func((void *)&somevar)` As we don't impact the variable value in any way (nor dereferencing NULL ptr) we don't do anything criminal.

Comment: Do you just not like the `atexit` function? Or `constructor` and `destructor` function attributes for `main`?

Comment: Other than - "If it is about memory management and exit cleanup: Why don't you leave that to the OS which is actually pretty good at it?" - You should be able to builds something like this around the `atexit()` call with quite a bit of complicated work (for the stacking of function parameters). Leaving it to the OS is way simpler, way more reliable, and way less error-prone.

Comment: Certainly possible, I'll post a solution when I've time (in about 3 to 5 hours)

Comment: Why not just use Go? ;-)

Comment: You can do something similar to defer using the [gcc extension](gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html) `__attribute__((cleanup(func)))`, and you can save function calls using the [gcc extension](gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html) `__builtin_apply_args`. There really is no portable way of doing this though because different architectures pass arguments differently so even if you do inline assembly or something, you can't just copy some of the stack because some arguments might be in registers. If you can't use gcc or standardize parameters, don't try this.

Comment: @hacatu Just in case you're interested: avcall from libffcall tries to hide the differences of the calling convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm experimenting with memory management and trying to create something that will help with it in any way.

A good approach is to have only one `return` in any function. Possibly marked with a label (yes, so can `goto`it, but this is also often discouraged). And of course: Be always sure to know who owns allocated memory and when (and where) ownership is transferred!

Now, let's...

> [..] repeat the 'defer' functionality from Go in C.

First, in order to defer the call, we need to store the function (a pointer to it) as well as the evaluated arguments. Since C is statically typed, we need to unify that in a single type:

```
struct Fn {
  void * parameters; // pointer to memory where the parameters are stored
  void (*function)(void *); // pointer to function able to unpack parameters from above
  struct Fn * next; // we want a stack, so ...
};
```

For each function that we are going to eventually defer, we need a way to store it's parameters. So we define a `struct` capable of holding the parameters and a function that is able to unpack the parameters from that `struct`:

```
#define MAKE_DEFERRABLE(name, N, ...) \
  struct deferred_ ## name ## _parameters { PARAMS(N, __VA_ARGS__) }; \
  void deferred_ ## name (void * p) { \
    struct deferred_ ## name ## _parameters * parameters = p; \
    printf(" -- Calling deferred " #name "\n"); \
    (void)name(CPARAMS(N)); \
  }
```

The `N` is the number of arguments. There are tricks to infer that from the `__VA_ARGS__`, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. That macro contains two other macro expansions, `PARAMS` and `CPARAMS`. The former expands into a list suitable to define the `struct` contents. The later expands into code to extract the `struct` members as arguments:

```
#define PARAM_0(...)
#define PARAM_1(type, ...) type p1; PARAM_0(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PARAM_2(type, ...) type p2; PARAM_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PARAM_3(type, ...) type p3; PARAM_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PARAM_4(type, ...) type p4; PARAM_3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PARAMS(N, ...) SPLICE(PARAM_, N)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define CPARAM_0 
#define CPARAM_1 parameters->p1
#define CPARAM_2 parameters->p2, CPARAM_1
#define CPARAM_3 parameters->p3, CPARAM_2
#define CPARAM_4 parameters->p4, CPARAM_3
#define CPARAMS(N) SPLICE(CPARAM_, N)
```

If we'd want to defer functions with more than 4 parameters then this would need to be adjusted. The `SPLICE` is a nice little helper:

```
#define SPLICE_2(l,r) l##r
#define SPLICE_1(l,r) SPLICE_2(l,r)
#define SPLICE(l,r) SPLICE_1(l,r)
```

Next, we need to store the deferred functions somehow. For simplicity I choose to allocate them dynamically and keep a global pointer to the most recent:

```
struct Fn * deferred_fns = NULL;
```

Obviously you can extend this in many directions: Using (bounded) static storage, making it thread local, using per function `deferred_fns`, using `alloca`, ...

... but here's the simple, not production-ready (**MISSING ERROR CHECKS**) variant:

```
#define DEFER(name, N, ...) \
  do { \
    printf(" -- Deferring a call to " #name "\n"); \
    if (deferred_fns == NULL) { \
      deferred_fns = malloc(sizeof(*deferred_fns)); \
      deferred_fns->next = NULL; \
    } else { \
      struct Fn * f = malloc(sizeof(*f)); \
      f->next = deferred_fns; \
      deferred_fns = f; \
    } \
    deferred_fns->function = &(deferred_ ## name); \
    struct deferred_ ## name ##_parameters * parameters = malloc(sizeof(*parameters)); \
    SPARAMS(N,__VA_ARGS__); \
    deferred_fns->parameters = parameters; \
  } while(0)
```

This just allocates a new `struct Fn`, makes it the top of the stack (read singly-linked list `deferred_fns`) and sets its members accordingly. The important `SPARAMS` saves the parameters into the corresponding `struct`:

```
#define SPARAM_0(...)
#define SPARAM_1(value, ...) parameters->p1 = (value); SPARAM_0(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SPARAM_2(value, ...) parameters->p2 = (value); SPARAM_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SPARAM_3(value, ...) parameters->p3 = (value); SPARAM_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SPARAM_4(value, ...) parameters->p4 = (value); SPARAM_3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SPARAMS(N, ...) SPLICE(SPARAM_, N)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

*Note: This fixes the order of parameter evaluation by making them evaluate from last to first. C does not mandate an evaluation order.*

Finally, all that's left is a convenient way to run these deferred functions:

```
void run_deferred_fns(void) {
  while (deferred_fns != NULL) {
    deferred_fns->function(deferred_fns->parameters);
    free(deferred_fns->parameters);
    struct Fn * bye = deferred_fns;
    deferred_fns = deferred_fns->next;
    free(bye);
  }
}
```

[A small test](http://ideone.com/fNKJU1):

```
void foo(int x) {
    printf("foo: %d\n", x);
}
void bar(void) {
    puts("bar");
}
void baz(int x, double y) {
    printf("baz: %d %f\n", x, y);
}
MAKE_DEFERRABLE(foo, 1, int);
MAKE_DEFERRABLE(bar, 0);
MAKE_DEFERRABLE(baz, 2, int, double);

int main(void) {
  DEFER(foo, 1, 42);
  DEFER(bar, 0);
  DEFER(foo, 1, 21);
  DEFER(baz, 2, 42, 3.14);
  run_deferred_fns();
  return 0;
}
```

In order to achieve the same behavior as in your example, make `deferred_fns` a local variable, and pass that as parameter to `run_deferred_fns`. Wrap in simple macros, done:

```
#define PREPARE_DEFERRED_FNS struct Fn * deferred_fns = NULL;
#define RETURN(x) do { run_deferred_fns(deferred_fns); return (x); } while (0)
```

Welcome to insanity.

*Note: My solution works at the "source level". By that I mean that you need to specify defer-able functions in the source code. That implies that you cannot, for example, defer a function loaded through `dlopen`. There's also a different approach, working at the ABI level, if you will: avcall, part of [libffcall](https://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/).*

Now, I need really need my parentheses ... *lots* of them (())))(()(((()

Comment: Thank you for the good answer! I think we can even move MAKE_DEFERRABLE to function definition with something like this:
`DEFERABLE(void, foo(int x, double b)) { ... }`. I've seen similar function-via-macro definitions many times even in good libraries (like libxml/fontconfig for example)

Comment: Yes, one could add such a macro. Having a `MAKE_DEFERRABLE` has the benefit of being able to make all statically known functions possible to defer. Like `fclose`, `printf` (for a single kind of invocation only, though) and other library functions :)

Comment: Sorry, too, late for the prev comment edit, making new. I think better return is: `#define RETURN  run_deferred_fns(); return` because this way we can write `RETURN 0;` or `RETURN ERROR_CODE;` without ruining basic return syntax. UPD: I'll try to work for removing the `MAKE_DEFERRABLE` macro, I think we can create generic call 'on-the-run'.

Comment: No, you should have it like in my answer. Think of what would happen with `if (condition) RETURN 42;` otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about this case. Sorry.